# How can I prevent clear Application Settings when program update?

Tags: c#, wpf

Currently, I am using the Application Setting(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/managing-application-settings-dotnet?view=vs-2022) to store the setting of my program.

And also, my program (WPF with .NET6) is compiling with Self-Contained/ReadyToRun/Single File.

Now I meet a problem: after the user updates the program by overwriting file, all the settings will be cleared.

I think it may consider the new version is a different program but not the same program that it creates a new setting.

However, it is not well for user experience.

How should I solve this? Thank you.

Comment: Tried persisting your settings somewhere, which doesn't get overwritten when you update your App?

Comment: @Cheesebaron The setting file is placed and controlled by windows not by me.

Comment: You could consider managing these settings yourself. I.e. by storing a json file in ApplicationData. This way you have control.

Comment: You should not use settings. Rather, build a class or classes whose properties hold these values. Serialise to appdata and deserialise from there.